# pandas list cursor error

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

Making a follow up question to a separate question i posted earlier. [Unable to create a second dataframe python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118259/unable-to-create-a-second-dataframe-python-pandas/40118556#40118556)

The error i figured out was when i try to make a list out of my cursor object, i could no longer call that cursor to say make another dataframe with it. See below:

```
strsql1 = "SELECT * FROM CRMCSVFILE"
cursor = cursor.execute(strsql1)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor)


strsql2 = "SELECT * FROM CRMSVFILE WHERE EMAIL = 'some email'"
cursor = cursor.execute(strsql1)
maxList = list(cursor)
#when i set maxList to list(cursor) i get an error on the next line
another_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor)
```

The error says that cursor is empty, and i want to know why when i take out the maxList = list(cursor) statement, that the code works fine and i can make as many dataframes as i want.

Comment: Once you iterate through the `cursor` object (i.e. when you call `list()`) on it, the cursor is empty, i.e. it's iterated through to the end of the result set.